# use django-guardian with Custom User

Tags: django, django-permissions, django-guardian

I use custom user And i want to django-guardian to handle the permissions and groups. How i can do that
my user:

```
class ProfileUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    departement= models.CharField(max_length=255)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a OneToOne field in the `ProfileUser` model that points to an actual user or use any other method included [in the django documentation about extending the user model.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  have you an example to how use OneToOne field ?

Comment: is a normal, django field. Use it just like the ForeignKey: `myfield = models.OneToOneField(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`